# Blender rendering only one frame, not the entire animation

Tags: rendering, animation

I've been going to other forums that seem like people had the same problem as me but all of the question threads I found either had outdated answers or no posted answers at all.

Every single time I render the animation it always renders only one frame, instead of the entire animation, creating only a half second video that doesn't even play just because it has only one frame.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are skiping 10,000 frames. Inside Frame Range, switch the steps to 1

Answer (score 1):

As @[Emir](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/66870/emir) has pointed out, the answer is in your screenshot:

[image]

Notice that you are using a step of $1000$ instead of $1$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties window, under the Output tab, scroll down to Post Processing and uncheck these two options, Pipeline Composting and Sequencer

[image: Output Settings]